# Dealing with List View Threshold

Tags: 2013, list-view-threshold

I have a list that has 5586 items so it has gone over the List View Threshold. I'm a site collection admin, but don't have access to central admin. So we can't change the limit. I've been trying to find ways to work with it, but in general they don't seem to work or the explanations leave a lot uncovered.

For example [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/168482/dealing-with-list-view-threshhold) the accepted answer is

> ...The first filter of a View must return less than the set List View Threshold...

But it doesn't explain how to have the first filter return less than 5000. In my case I have a single person column called **Claimed by**. Through other means I have figured out that there are 2136 items with an empty value there; well under 5000. I've tried filtering the list with this field equal to "blank" or even a specific name and I get the thresh hold message.

I thought it might be because I needed to index the column which is recommended in several other threads or tutorials. In [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-an-index-to-a-sharepoint-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0#__supportedcolumns) it mentions:

> If you are adding an index to avoid a List View Threshold error, ensure that the field used is not a lookup field. Please see supported column to determine which field types are lookup fields.

Futher down it mentions that the following are lookups: person or group, managed metadata, and lookup. So even though they can be indexed they don't help with the threshold. Unfortunately all the columns that would naturally divide up our list into chunks of less than 5000 are one of those three types.

I'm also trying to work with another list that will soon go over 5000. Again the only things that would naturally divide that list into chunks smaller than 5000 are one of those types. Except this second list also has different content types.

I see that I can create an index of the Content type, but I don't know if it is a column that can be used as a first value to address the limit. Using a REST call to `/_api/list('guid')/Fields` I see that the ContentType column is of type "Computed." But I know from other REST stuff that ContentType is a column that needs to be expanded -- like a person or lookup column.

Does anybody know if an ContentType index can be used as a first filter to work within the 5000 List View item thresh hold?

Does anybody have a strategy for filtering if all the appropriate columns are of the forbidden people, metadata, or lookup types?

Comment: As you are site col admin your index might not be created correctly. There is larger limit for administrators (but for that to work user needs to be administrator on the front end not farm administrator). For proper index creation you need ask you SP admins to create an index with user that falls under above requirements.

Comment: I used the content type as in large list queries before, but I am not sure was that the first clause.

Comment: and i don't think you can create index on unsupported column, If it is in the dropdown you can create it.